# How to handle iphone keyboard done button in application preferences setting like Music application

Tags: iphone

I m working on iphone application which contains username and password field in applications preferences setting. i want to validate username and password on some websites when user press return button like Music application of iPod which validates apple id and password on done.
Also want to know how to change keyboard return key to Done button in preferences textFiled.

Comment: In the settings app, or on a settings section in your own app?

Comment: I want in the settings app. Thanx for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in the central settings app. It is not possible to run your own code there, you can just tell it what sorts of data can be input.

Apple, of course, are not bound by this restriction so they can do what they like in the settings app.

If you want login controls and authentication then this would have to be done within your app - which makes sense from the users point of view anyway, they don't want to have to switch to settings to start using your app.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a function in place to validate the userName and Password when you press the return key.

**PART I : Validate Credential on WebSite**

Implement the delegate method of UITextField such as

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (textField == txtfEmail)
        [txtfPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    else {
        [self login];           
    }   
    return YES;
}
```

This will make Password field as next responder when Next (return) key is pressed, later while password field is done then as user presses Done (return) key It will make a call to Login Method

```
-(void)login {

    if([self validateLoginCredentials]) {
        iDNUser* currentUser = [[iDNUser alloc] init];
        currentUser.strEmail = txtfuserId.text;
        currentUser.strPwd = txtfpassword.text;

        if (!wsRequestObject) {
            wsRequestObject = [[iDNWebServiceInterface alloc] initWithTarget:self andReturnType:kiDNUserPacket];
        }
        [wsRequestObject loginUser:currentUser];
        [currentUser release];
    }

}
```

Here **iDNWebServiceInterface** is a custom class that calls a JOSN based Webserivce on server to validate user.

You can handle this part (Calling server methods) as per your convenience and server implementation of your webservices.

//--------------

```
- (BOOL)validateLoginCredentials {
    BOOL isValid = NO;
    if ([txtfuserId isFirstResponder]) {
        [txtfuserId resignFirstResponder];
    }
    if ([txtfpassword isFirstResponder]) {
        [txtfpassword resignFirstResponder];
    }
    UIAlertView* errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    if ([txtfuserId.text length] > 0 ) {
        if ([txtfpassword.text length] > 0) {
            isValid = YES;
        }
        else 
        {
            [errorAlert setTitle:@"Message"];
            [errorAlert setMessage:@"Password can not be blank."];
            [errorAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
            [errorAlert setCancelButtonIndex:0];
            [errorAlert show];
            [txtfpassword becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    else {
        [errorAlert setTitle:@"Message"];
        [errorAlert setMessage:@"User Id can not be blank."];
        [errorAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
        [errorAlert setCancelButtonIndex:0];
        [errorAlert show];  
        [txtfuserId becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    [errorAlert release];
    return isValid;
}
```

Will help you decide as well as notify user about any missing field.

**Part II : how to change the return key to done**

With XCode 3.2.x you can select the textfield and open up the Attribute Inspector by pressing Cmd + 1

Here you can set the return type to anything from the predefined list as shown in screenshot

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Rahul thanx for reply. Actually i want to change keyboard return key in setting.bundle. and also want to validate username and password from setting.bundle. like you can find same thing in ipod Music application's bundle setting. is it possible?